# How do you make a bootable micro SD card

Tags: boot

I have a pine A64 2GB RAM, I am trying to put ubuntu on a micro SD so I can boot the computer with it. The original micro SD that it came with was super glitchy. The micro sd registers as two different removable drives when I plug it in.

Comment: please clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

Steps to install Ubuntu from Windows

**Pre-Install setup**

1) Download the latest image from longsleeps folder (https://www.stdin.xyz/downloads/people/l...es/ubuntu/)

2) Download Win32Imager (h**ps://sourceforge.net/projects/win32di...t/download)

3) Have some kind of extraction capabilities (7zip - h**p://www.7-zip.org)

4) Have a Micro SD card (and adapter to enable it to plug into a USB port) ready, at least 8GB (Class 10 if you can)

5) Have a decent power supply (at least 2a) and shorter cables are better.

**Setup**

1) Extract the image, and Install the Win32Imager somewhere (preferably the same folder!)

2) Open Win32imager and write the image to the SD card (ensure you have the SD card selected!)

3) Once the write has completed, MAKE SURE you safely remove the USB drive from the PC – not doing so may harm the write process.

4) Remove the SD card and put in the Pine64. Ensure you only have the REQUIRED peripherals connected, Keyboard, HDMI, and I would say LAN too, THEN connect the power.

5) Let the Pine64 boot. When completed, use username: ubuntu and password: ubuntu to login; it’s also worth mentioning that once you see the login screen, you CAN ssh into the pine64 also, if you so prefer.

6) Once logged in, run the following:  /usr/local/sbin/resize_rootfs.sh
this will resize the / partition to fill the SD card.

Congratulations, you should now have a working system.

> **Source:** [PINE64 Forums](https://forum.pine64.org/showthread.php?tid=622)